# Highlight row color based on field values in Sharepoint 2010 list view

Tags: list-view

Can anyone give idea how we can change the row color based on the corresponding field values in Sharepoint 2010 list view?

Comment: Is this issue solved. Could you pls explain how can we solve this using SD2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is :

1. Go to SharePoint Designer 2010
2. Go to your list, open the list view you want to modify
3. in ribbon, select **Options [Tab] - Conditional Formatting - Format Row** option.

It should be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to do that is by using conditional formatting with SharePoint Designer. but it has its disadvantages -  it messes up grouped views and more other things. Besides SharePoint designer I can recommend on custom development or 3rd party product like we have here in Infowise – Color Field. You should give it a look -http://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=ColorField

Answer (score 1):

My colleague has written up a post detailing the different ways to do this - [How to do list highlighting in SharePoint](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/how-to-do-list-highlighting-in-sharepoint/)

It includes

- SharePoint Designer
- Javasript & Content Editor Web Parts
- Custom Columns via Visual Studio
- and of course 3rd party products 
  *(disclaimer, one of which is
  from my company)*

Answer (score 0):

There are third party add-ons([sharepoint highlight rows](http://www.sharepointadd-ons.com/sharepoint-highlight-rows)) that allows you highlight SharePoint list rows based on field values.