# Display an image based on date range

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, calculated-column

I have a SharePoint list of devices that are checked out or reserved by a personnel. We check them out or reserve them based on the requested dates that has a start date to finish date column.

How would I go about displaying in a new column called status a Green Image for Active and Yellow for upcoming? I would like this to dynamically update based on the dates provided.

So that for example a reservation date of 08/06/2014 - 08/09/2014 is displayed in green for Device #1. Then another reservation for the same device with the dates of 08/10/2014 08/15/2014 is displayed in yellow.

Once the green reservation end date is passed it will change to red for inactive and then we can delete it.

Is this possible or would a Nintex workflow be better suited for this?

Just look for some direction or a small example not a full solution.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/how-to-do-list-highlighting-in-sharepoint/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/balsharfi/archive/2011/10/20/sharepoint-lists-conditional-formatting-using-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx

It includes

- SharePoint Designer
- Javasript & Content Editor Web Parts
- Custom Columns via Visual Studio
- and of course 3rd party products 
  *(disclaimer, one of which is
  from my company)*

Comment: Copied from : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7478/highlight-row-color-based-on-field-values-in-sharepoint-2010-list-view